# No usb or Ethernet after installation

Tags: usb, ethernet

I'm writing this using mobile phone.
I installed Ubuntu latest, but only usb 3.0 ports are working, Ethernet and usb 2.0 seems to be recognized but not functioning, and this also happened on Fedora and Linux Mint. 
I took screenshots with my phone of the terminal:

[image]

[image]